# Yii2: How to add multiple TD rows inside one TR?

Tags: yii2

What I need to achieve is to add multiple `td` rows in one `tr`. F.e:

```
<tr>
<td="0"> row1 </td>
<td="1"> row2 </td>
<td="2"> row3 </td>
</tr>
```

How can I achieve it? I'm trying like so:

```
 $td = Html::tag('td data-col-seq', [
    '0' => 'test' 
    '1' => 'test2'
 ]);

 return Html::tag('tr', $td);
```

But I get `Array to string conversion` error, besides that, I don't get the `values`. All I get is `<td data-col-seq 0="test"> NO VALUE HERE </td>`

I hope you understood the problem. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve your problem is as follows

```
    $cols = '';
    $row = '';
    $data = [0, 1, 2];  //just a sample here

    // create all td tags at first based on your sample  
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        $cols .= Html::tag('td', 'rows' . $value, [
            'value' => $value,
        ]);
    }

    $row .= Html::tag('tr', $cols);  //then create a tr tag to include all td tags
    var_dump($row);
```

The first param of `Html::tag` function is the tag name, second one is the content inside the tag that you just created, last one is the attrs attached to the tag.

The reason why you came accross that error is that the second param needs to be string type, while you passed an array, which should be the last param. May this you help.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you need  a td tag with row1 conttnet and data-col-seq as attribute you should use

```
  $options = ['data-col-seq' => 'your-values'];
  echo Html::tag('a', 'row1', $options);
```

for several value .. build te proper code using a loop
see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-html.html for reference and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html for guide